# JS Strict Mode - Accessing boolean variable

Tags: javascript, scope, strict-mode

So I've looked all over Stack Overflow and found similar questions, but couldn't find one that I could apply to mine.  I'm in strict mode, and I have defined a variable (loaded = false), and trying to do an if/else statement based on where it's true or false... and after it runs once, I want it to switch to "true" so it won't run again.  Below is the code:

```js
"use strict"
let loaded = false;
if (loaded === false) {
  //do an action
  loaded = true;
}
```

But I get an error at 'loaded = true' which says "the value assigned is never used".  I'm assuming this is a scoping issue, but I'm not sure how else to do it?

Thanks!

*More Detail:
This is the code I'm working with.. obviously some of it isn't readable since other variables are used, but maybe this will help.

```
let loaded = false;

  if (loaded === false) {
    // animate swipe on map load
    this.view.when().then((() => {
    setTimeout(() => { // delay 1500ms for the map to load a bit
      $(".movable").animate({left: "50%"},
        {
         duration: 1200,
         easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
         step: (function (now, fx) {
         this._setOption('swipeX', layerViewContainer.element.width * now / 100);
        }).bind(this)
      });
     }, 1800);
    }).bind(this));
   loaded = true;
  }
```

So you see, I'm trying to set the variable to true, so that it won't run again while they are doing actions on the page... for some reason changing something on the page will reanimate the swipe (which I don't want to happen).

Comment: That's not an error, it's just a warning coming from some linter that you're using. When you write more code that actually uses `loaded` (you intend to do this, right?) it will go away.

Comment: You haven't showed the outer function but of course when executed again loaded is going to be created and set to false once more.

Comment: @Dominic that's a good point.. then how would I create the loop so it only happens once (in this case, when the page loads)?

Comment: @ChaseMartin any script tag executed at the bottom of `<body>` will get run once, or you can use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', yourOnDocReadyFunc)`. I just meant that if this code is in a re-usable function then it will get set to false each time.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't a scoping issue.

1. First, you set it to `false`.
2. Then your `if` reads the value so the value is used.
3. Then you assign a new value to it (`true`).
4. Then you get to the end.

Your code never reads `loaded` after you change it, so the linter complains because you set it with no purpose that it can find.